# Syncfusion license and an invalid 64-base char array. Builds fine for everybody else

Tags: syncfusion, licenses.licx

I get this error on a Visual studio solution that I did not create myself, when trying to build it:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at Syncfusion.Licensing.PublicKeyDecrypt.SyncfusionDecode(String key)
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.UnlockKeyInfo..ctor(String key, String filterVersion)
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.Sweep.GetUnlockKeyInfos()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicenseLog.GetErrorKind()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicenseErrorDialog.GetErrorText()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicenseErrorDialog.InitializeErrorLabel()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicenseErrorDialog.InitializeUI()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicenseErrorDialog..ctor(LicenseLog log)
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I know for a fact that it works for other people. I suspect something's not right with my Syncfusion installation, though Syncfusion does appear in the list of plugins, and in its License Manager there is the license I used when installing it.

I don't know where to look anymore... I've asked Syncfusion's support but haven't been getting an answer

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for using Syncfusion products.

From your update, we found that multiple version of syncfusion.core has been referred in your project.

Please follow the steps mentioned below to resolve the reported error.

1) Open your Visual Studio project file in any text editor and ensure that only one Syncfusion.Core reference entry exists in your project.

2) If more than one Syncfusion.Core entry exists in your project, please remove those entries and ensure that only one Syncfusion.Core entry exists in your project.

3) Remove the license.licx file from the project (if its present) and reload your project in Visual Studio, because Syncfusion had removed run time license from version 8.2. So no need to add this file in your project which uses our latest version assemblies.

4) Ensure that all Syncfusion referenced assemblies in the project belongs to same version of Syncfusion, for ex 10.3.0.43.